# Spacing between elements with a DIV

Tags: html, css

`Figma.com` use DIV with a specific height for spacing between a form element in their sign up form.

For example:

```html
<input name="email" type="text" value="">
<div style="height: 24px;"></div>
<input name="password" type="password" value="">
```

Is it good practice and what I can use instead?

[figma sign up form markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNGZl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same can be done using stuff like margin instead of adding an empty div element; (though it doesnt say) I think Figma has a flexbox with a column (which would explain their reasoning for an empty div). As usual, the same effect the div is creating can be done also with a section tag, but unless you absolutely have to according to your layout, I would just stay simple and do the same effect with a margin instead.

Comment: But what effect they want to achieve by using div for spacing in the flexbox? I'm always using margin either

Comment: Like I said before, for tabled layouts such as columns or flexboxes, it is very normal to see people using empty divs. Sometimes it is to create elaborate effects with media queries, and other times an extra parameter they can style as well. Think of an empty div as padding that doesn't extend the content. It is just there so that, if needed, extra CSS (or maybe even JS) can be applied later.

Answer (score 0):

the `<div>` element doesn't have semantic meaning in the HTML page. You can use it for spacing, but I would do it with CSS to speed up DOM performance a little bit:

```css
/* CSS */
input {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```